# Intershop: How To Delete a Channel After Orders Have Been Created

Tags: intershop

I am able to delete a channel from the back office UI and run the DeleteDomainReferences job in SMC to clear the reference and be able to create a new channel again with the same id.

However, once an order has been created, the above mentioned process won't work.

I heard that we can run some stored procedures against the database for situation like this.

Question: what are the stored procedures and steps to take to be able to clean any reference in Intershop so that I can create a channel with the same id again?

Update 9/26:
I did configure a new job in SMC to call DeleteDomainReferencesTransaction pipeline with ToBeRemovedDomainID attribute set to the domain id that I am trying to clean up.

The job ran without error in the log file. The job finished almost instantly, though.

Then I ran the DeleteDomainReferences job in SMC. This is the job I normally run after deleting a channel when there is no order in that channel. This job failed the following exception in the log file.

ORA-02292: integrity constraint (INTERSHOP.BASKETADDRESS_CO001) violated - child record found
ORA-06512: at "INTERSHOP.SP_DELETELINEITEMCTNRBYDOMAIN", line 226
ORA-06512: at line 1

Then I checked BASKETADDRESS table and did see the records for that domain id.  This is, I guess, the reason why DeleteDomainReferences job failed.

I also execute the SP_BASKET_OBSERVER with that domain id, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I'll try it out on my own machine, i'll get back to u.

Comment: Which version are you on? I guess 7.8 or higher?

Comment: I am using 7.8.1.4

Comment: yeah, I'm pretty sure this is a bug in 7.8. In 7.7 it did still work.

Comment: Is there a way to work around that bug in 7.8.1.4 ?

Comment: There is definitely a workaround. I dont have a 7.8 environment at hand to debug the issue however. Intershop support would be able to give you a solution pretty quickly. Can you submit this bug to them?

Comment: Did you get an answer from support for this problem

Comment: I have been in contact with the support and have just generated database dump and uploaded to the ftp site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the assistance from intershop support, it has been determined that, in IS 7.8.1.4, the sp_deleteLineItemCtnrByDomain.sql has issue.

line 117 and 118 from 7.8.1.4

```
delete from staticaddress_av where ownerid in (select uuid from staticaddress where lineitemctnrid = i.uuid);
delete from staticaddress where lineitemctnrid = i.uuid;
```

should be replaced by

```
delete from basketaddress_av where ownerid in (select uuid from basketaddress where basketid = i.uuid);
delete from basketaddress where basketid = i.uuid;
```

After making the stored procedure update, running DeleteDomainReference job finishes without error and I was able to re-create the same channel again.

The fix will become available in 7.8.2 hotfix as I was told.

Answer (score 0):

```
sp_deleteLineItemCtnrByDomain
-- Description : This procedure deletes basket/order related stuff.
-- Input       : domainID   The domain id of the domain to be deleted.
-- Output      : none
-- Example     : exec sp_deleteLineItemCtnrByDomain(domainid)
```

This stored procedure should delete the orders. Look up the domainid that you want to delete in the domaininformation table and call this procedure.

You can also call the pipeline `DeleteDomainReferencesTransaction`. Setup an smc job that calls this pipeline with the domainid that you want to clean up as a parameter. It also calls a second sp that cleans up the payment data so it actually a better approach.

Update 9/27

I tried this out on my local 7.7 environments. The DeleteDomainReferences job also removes the orders from the isorder table. No need to run sp_deleteLineItemCtnrByDomain separately. Recreating the channel I see no old orders. I'm guessing that you discovered a bug in the version you are running. Maybe related to the address table being split into [different tables](https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/28056N). Open a ticket for support to have them look at this.

Comment: Tried what was suggested. Please see the update in the original question